# Почему через Nginx не могу зайти в APP в контейнере на VDS?

Tags: nginx, docker

Открыл порт через

```
sudo ufw allow 200
```

Прохожу по адресу VDS:

> http://100.100.100.100:200

Мне ответ:

> Не удается получить доступ к сайту Веб-страница по адресу http://100.100.100.100:200/, возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу.
> ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

Конфиг компоса:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    links:
      - db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: p_app
    command: python wsgi.py

  nginx:
    #volumes:
    #  - ./file/fullchain.pem:/etc/nginx/fullchain.pem
    #  - ./file/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/privkey.pem
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: p_nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 200:85
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Конфиг nginx:

```
server {
        listen 85;
        server_name 100.100.100.100;
        location / {
                        include uwsgi_params;
                        uwsgi_pas app:5000;
   }
}
```

Строка запуска из wsgi.py:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: ERR_UNSAFE_PORT намекает на то, что браузер принципиально отказывается подключаться к настолько нестандартному порту

Comment: Спасибо, поменял на другой порт - заработало, а то голову ломал)))